# RexExp Passing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a problem with passing variables into a `regExp`.

Here my code:

```
project.highlight = function($st,$search) {
    re = new RegExp("/\b("+ $search +")\b/g");
    return $st.replace(/\b(lorem)\b/g, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');  // working
    return $st.replace(re, '<span class="highlight">$1</span>');  // not working...
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean if you try 1st return, its working, and if you are trying with the 2nd, its not?

Comment: No. im hiding one when testing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re = new RegExp("\\b("+ $search +")\\b", "g");
```

With this syntax you must remove delimiters and put the modifier at the end in a separate string. (and use double slashes)